# Ratio of verification to RTL design code?

Tags: verilog, verification, system-verilog

In a typical industry Verilog/SystemVerilog IP/SOC design, what is the ratio of verification code to RTL design code?

The ratio can be given in terms of lines of code (excluding comments) or a similar measurement unit.

**Definitions:**

- RTL design code -- code that will be synthesized into FPGA/ASIC gates for the final chip
- verification code -- code used to verify the functionality of RTL design code, including test environment, checks, randomization, and functional coverage

**Motivation:**

The motivation for this question is an investigation I'm doing on the number of verification bugs versus RTL design bugs. I expect the number of bugs is correlated to code size. So, if the ratio of verification:design bugs is wildly higher than the code size ratio, this could signal a bigger problem with the verification approach.

Comment: Some say that 2.5:1 (verification:design).

Comment: 3:1 (V:D) on effort, often squeezed to 1:1 for devices with bugs.

Comment: Not really sure this is a good metric. I can do the same thing in e with 5 lines that I can do in SystemVerilog with 50 (just random numbers), but I wouldn't say that the smaller number of lines in the e testbench indicates a buggy design.

Comment: Are you thinking in terms of engineering effort expended or simulation performance?  For example if using UVM and you include the library code, expand all the macros etc. you instantly have significant amounts of code!

Comment: Agree with @Tudor it depends massively on the technology used.  I've also observed a reduction in lines of code by a factor of 10 in the cases where we've migrated an existing testbench from SV (UVM) to Python.

Comment: @Chiggs, I'm thinking in terms of engineering effort. Ultimately, I'm trying to estimate what a reasonable ratio of verification:design bugs should be.